# Ember.js - child nested views' controller

Tags: view, controller, ember.js

I'm building a simple calendar app with Ember. My views are nested this way :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="calendar">
    {{content.monthAsString}}
    {{#each day in content.days}}
       {{view App.DayView contentBinding="day"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name'="calendarDay">
    {{content.date}}
</script>
```

My JS code :

```
App.CalendarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content:App.Calendar.create(...);
    oneDayHover:function(day){

    }
});
App.CalendarView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:"calendar"
});

App.CalendarDayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    dayHOver:function(){
        //???? HOW TO ACCESS CalendarController?????
    }
});
App.CalendarDayView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:"calendarDay",
    init:function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('controller', App.CalendarDayController.create());
    },
    mouseEnter:function(){
        this.get('controller').dayHover();
    }
});
```

Problem 1:
Isn't there a nicer solution than to override the init method of the view to set it's controller?

Problem 2:
How can I access the oneDayHover of CalendarController from the CalendarDayController?

Thanks in advance for the help

**Update 1:**
I should remark that those controllers exists in the same state. The point of the mouseenter is to display a popup on top of the CalendarDayView containing extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 - Do not assign Controllers to Views manually.** Let Ember do the heavy Lifting! Have a look at Embers Router API / how to define routes. Routes will connect controllers and views and render them ([Doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/)).

**2 -** If you follow point 1, your other problem will get easy with Embers way of dependency injection:

```
App.CalendarDayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs : ["calendar"],
    dayHOver:function(){
        //Access the single instance of CalendarController
        var calendarController = this.get("controllers.calendar");
    }
});
```

**Update in response to Comment:**

The CalendarRoute is created implicitly. Therefore all you would need to do, is modifying your template, i guess:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="calendar">
    {{content.monthAsString}}
    {{#each day in content.days}}
       {{control "calendarDay" day}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

As you see, i am suggesting the use of the **{{control}}** helper. What the code above basically says is :

> "Dear Ember, please use the name 'calendarDay' to lookup
>   App.CalendarView and App.CalendarDayController and use them to render
>   the object day"

Additionally you have to tell ember, that it should **not use the controller as singleton** (which is the defaul behaviour):

```
App.register('controller:calendarDay', App.CalendarDayController, {singleton: false });
```

**Note:** I have not yet used the control helper myself, but this should be the way it works.

Comment: Thx for the quick feedback but I'm not sure I need a route as the controllers are in the same state. I should update the post and add this information. Is there a way to declare a route applying to this case?

Comment: Hi mavilein, Thanks again for the update. I tried the control helper. It could be the solution but now all calendarDayView are link to the same say. It's like ember instanciate one instance of the calendarDayController and reuse it when necessary... Do you know a trick to fix that?

Comment: Strange. Then i have not fully understand the purpose of this helper yet. This is an issue on the Github project: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1990 .They propose to make this particular controller non-singleton, e.g.: Reader = Ember.Application.create({});
Reader.register('controller:index_image', Reader.IndexImageController, {singleton: false });

Comment: In your case it would have to be:
App = Ember.Applicatio.create();
App.register('controller:calendarDay', App.CalendarDayController, {singleton: false });

Comment: Hi, Yeah I tried with the register and it works... Thanks again... maybe you should add this trick in the solution ;-)

Comment: Yeah! I will add it when i am back at a pc :-)